# Parameters for Daydream

Tags: google-vr

Does anybody have the parameters of the daydream headset?

I need the parameters of the Daydream in order to add it as a supported device to our VR sites.

The QR codes found in https://www.reddit.com/r/daydream/comments/5cfkvm/daydream_view_qrcode/ are either broken or from another headset.

The extracted short url from the QR code should look like this:

```
vendor: "BOBOVR Z3"
model: "BOBOVR Z3"
screen_to_lens_distance: 0.045
inter_lens_distance: 0.06
left_eye_field_of_view_angles: 75
left_eye_field_of_view_angles: 75
left_eye_field_of_view_angles: 75
left_eye_field_of_view_angles: 75
tray_to_lens_distance: 0.038
distortion_coefficients: 0.25
distortion_coefficients: 0.0001
has_magnet: false
vertical_alignment: BOTTOM
```

Comment: similar: https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill/issues/182

Comment: Daydream uses the same params as V2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daydream uses the same params as V2 https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill/issues/182